# Is it faster or better to use MySQL instead of text files or file names for order of images with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have images being stored in folders related to articles on my PHP web site, and would like to set the order to display the images based on author input. I started by naming the files with a number in front of them, but was considering recording the order in a text file instead to avoid renaming every file and retaining their original file names, or possibly storing the order in a MySQL table.

My question is about best practice and speed - every time the article is loaded, it will have to find out the order of images to display them. I was hoping to get some input about which method would be best and fastest.

For example, is it much slower to read a list of file names in a folder with PHP, or open a text file and read the contents, compared to making MySQL query and update statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say a lot depends on your base hardware/filesystem/mysql connection performances. A single access to disk, just to read images is most likely going to be your quickest option. But you'd need to name your files manually ahead.

Mysql requires a TCP or *NIX socket connection, and this might slow down things (a lot depends on the number of pictures you have, and the "quality" of your db link, though). If you have a lot of files, performance hit might be negligible. Just reading from a file might be quicker nevertheless, without bothering to set up a DB connection; you'd still have to write down ID/filename correspondence for the ordering though.

Something I'd try out in your situation is to take a look at the php stat command, and see if it can help you out sorting the pictures. Depending on the number of pictures you have (it works better with lower numbers), performance might not get a serious performance hit, and you'd be able NOT to keep a separate list of picture/creation date tuples. As your number of pictures grow, the file list approach seems to me like a reasonable way to solve the problem. Just benchmarking the thing as the number of pictures increases can tell you the truth, though. Since, I think, you can expect to have lot of variability, depending on your specific context.

Comment: Oh thanks, the stat command is useful for a variety of things related to the images!

Comment: just watch out, because it can get slow, if you have many entries in a single dir. How many pictures are we talking about?

Comment: I guess up to 100 or so images for the "gallery" type articles, and around 10-20 images per regular article seems fair.

Answer (score 2):

if your concern is performance why don't you save the list (maybe already formatted in HTML) to a file. When your page is loaded just read the file with

`$code = file_get_contents("cache_file.html")`

and output to the user. The fastest solution is to store the file as .html and let apache serve it directly, but this works only if your page doesn't have any other dinamic part.

to ensure that your cache file is up to date you can make it invalid and recreate it after some time (the specific time depends from the frequency in image changes) or check if the directory is changed after the cache file creation date. If you can trigger the changes in the image directory (for example if the changes are made from a piece of code that you wrote you can always ensure that you cache is refreshed when the images are changed)

Hope this helps

Comment: you could use an xml db to create an array without sql too

Comment: Uhmm... this XML tip just to keep track of an ordered list seems to me like shooting w/ bazooka to ants ;-) For just a list, why bother with something inherently complex as an XML doc? An .ini file is probably enough. SQLite might be a decent option too. Don't you think?

Comment: I like the cache file idea, once the order is saved then just generate the HTML and include that as needed.

Comment: Rule number one never ever ever use XML if you are not forced by some evil genius :-). That said my idea is to cache the data in a raw html file (full page or fragments) and than serve the code directly. You don't have the need to parse the content. Just display it or recreate it

Comment: Saving the ordered pictures in an html file? And what if someone wants to change the order? Then you read the html file back in and parse it to get the previous order? If it's not really an answer to the question but more like an addition ("Whatever the choice, you could then save the ... ergo: caching"), you might want to state that somewhat clearer. :-)

Comment: sure it's good to cache ahead as much as you can. Improved performance brings reduced flexibility, though. The point is IMHO understanding what you need the most in your context. And don't optimize w/ the risk of losing flexibility, if you don't need too (IE if you cache the whole presentation layer, it's then not so easy for you to, say, take the 5 most recent pics only...). Again, just 2cc. Good luck! ;-)

Comment: The question is about performance, and a raw html cache is the faster way there. As i've said in the post you have to choose a way to ensure that your cache is invalidated and recreated when needed but it's not difficult. I'm the first to say that if you have 10 files and 10 visitors forget about optimization "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." (http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Answer (score 2):

This smells like premature optimization.

> My question is about best practice and speed - every time the article is loaded, it will have to find out the order of images to display them.

So? A query like "select filename, title from images where articleId=$articleId order by 'order'"  will execute within a fraction of a second. It really doesn't matter. Do whatever is the easiest to do, and might I suggest that being the SQL option.

Comment: I agree with the possible premature optimization issue here. From what he told us, it seemed to me that he had files on a FS, not on a DB. Hence I think it's the mysql thing to be the overkill feature... Just my 2CC though. It's certainly wise to warn against the root of all evil :-D

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the images are on disk or in a db (which is also stored on disk, but alas). OP is talking about articles, which he (or at least I hope) stores in some kind of database. While having a connection open to retrieve the article contents, he might as well execute a query to get the order of the images. When in Rome... ;-)

Comment: @CodeCaster you're definitely right. Unless number of images is low so that stat can be hist best option (a separate list is not needed), if a link to db is up already, no need to look for trouble handling files. PS+1d ...but missed the "when in Rome" point :0|

Comment: It's an expression which I think can be translated to the situation I sketched, meaning "When you already have a database connection open...". :-) Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: tough to find something to correct in a sentence making 100% sense ;-)

Answer (score 1):

imho, using mysql would be slower, but oh so much easier. if the mysql server is hosted on the same server (or within dedicated space on the same server, like cloud linux), then it probably wont save too much time

**edit**

if you want to do a test, you can use the microtime function to time exactly how long it takes to append and sort the files, and how long it takes to get it all from mysql

Comment: It is shared hosting, and I guess the MySQL server is in the same datacenter, but it does not get connected to with localhost, so I guess it is another computer at least.

Comment: @miahelf then filename will be the fastest, i had a similar project a while ago, but resorted to mysql db because it was much easier to handle the file sorting

Comment: I guess that's what I was thinking but wanted some input, seems like making extra connections and queries to an SQL database can sometimes cause a site to lag while trying to communicate with another server.

Comment: @miahelf it does all depend on how its laid out. on my one, its all on the same box, and doing scandir took much longer than the mysql connection. but you could use a file instead of a database that list the files and positions like wezzy said. ive started making xml my main choice for storing information on mysql servers that are not on the same webserver.