# Using a text table instead of a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, performance, memory, runtime

I have a PHP program that uses a MySQL table with about 23000 rows. I noticed that the table is used only in a query of the form "SELECT * FROM [table]". So, in order to make my program easier to install, I thought of removing MySQL altogether, putting the table in a text file (e.g. tab-separated-values format), and whenever there is a "SELECT * FROM [table]" query, just read the entire table from the text file into memory.

What may be the disadvantages of such change? Will the program be substantially slower or consume substantially more memory? How can I measure these effects?

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003454/is-it-faster-or-better-to-use-mysql-instead-of-text-files-or-file-names-for-orde

Comment: Or also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206131/should-i-use-a-text-file-or-a-database-for-a-php-visitor-counter

Comment: One of the things that you'll want to consider about using text files for this, is putting them outside of your `public` folders or if you can use `.htaccess` on your server, then use that to protect them from prying eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference will be indexing. Scanning the file for values will be much slower than letting the MySQL do it for you.

If you start writing your own indexing scheme you are then opening up a world of hurt.

If you really do need every row from the table every time with no indexing, sorting, etc then a flat file will be far more efficient and a much better way to do this.

Comment: As I said, all queries are only "SELECT * FROM [table]" - there is no "where" clauses. In this case, is the indexing issue relevant?

Comment: See edited response. Do you really need to read a full 23k rows every time the PHP is called though? That sounds horribly inefficient.